# Ubuntu 16.04 Postfix works, but email goes to SPAM

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, spam

Hello i follow this guide to install Postfix

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

and i added SPF, dmarc and DKIM 
I follow this guide for dkim https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM

But still email going to SPAM.

Verification's:

```
dig +short txt muhammadumerfarooq.me

"google-site-verification=L6ZS4-VgKMcG1cGygBfywF84DI-ANF4g6rrzninNbsI"
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\010MIICXQIBAAKBgQDW25bTkpFlqxFhUG1kgTtSVGq0jloWB0rN7iNdXy/6OHZIUvmm\01040cZkqCn+AuiOeKYR68uA/wRabS2z3TkX2Xm25y4XArbc7LzRDg4M" "Eo79bm+q/Hr\010RBfgkvKs7namKBP7krdXNDg0Das14+DQ5hNlKgyyfeH5ZHXsfli64zJnwwIDAQAB\010AoGBAKeWE+jm074HVsEe6JSSMGEhMzGuLxorie9iJfd4fYWgcLIs9klz0UtjESiy\0100vAwUkwQ" "7dToir5SQwCshDJ1LpcarXlHTTt+wszEzvQsML8uv6HtfMLI8u3q9g0D\010Vx266tK5CYUUV4JBJP1/a/CfUvaNwcG9LNHs5ECpUqE58t5xAkEA9whbib14P9of\0104iKIV3Q32+4ABPDTenbZMG7LXtFz" "1hktNDUMTV+KIwb3WTc4e4DO3U2wlks48/15\010arRqW6up/wJBAN6oPBCt/P0l3Iedv/olDkUC0c60VCAt1wxG9rKw1wD6KrpQlRdc\010cRoxBszhn/jaQKOVadD/+Yg/aRAUZr35Gj0CQQCDvEQ8dvra" "ajLYf/vfT02+jfQa\010rmbIhvqZlmwDm4S/ZtuxXJy74jgjJ8LeI9GOIwmuAJEsBN9RVhnaqm2Rh0D3AkAq\010tKXgpR5zB4IG2PDrb5QPFH1dYiUIjwJCLpI+r8BtRY5QcghGlMp0tZaSUWw3dNUV\010CyF" "intYjldX26ZLTOSYZAkBeaZwaCPT/Y/sMf0iVGhxbwcn8DJmTLMW6uLtzdWyG\010NWHaANKPwNqsl8426ZZ27YPtPUJpaFxTBy5mE2K+UXSc\010-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
"v=spf1 include:_mailcust.gandi.net ?all"


dig +short txt _dmarc.muhammadumerfarooq.me

"v=DMARC1;p=quarantine;pct=100;v=DMARC1;p=reject;pct=50;v=DMARC1;p=none;rua=mailto:contact@muhammadumerfarooq.me"
```

Is there any way to fix this?

### Edit

Sometime email get back to me with following Output:

```
This is the mail system at host server.muhammadumerfarooq.me.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<mumerfarooqlablnet01@gmail.com>: host
    gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c07::1b] said: 550-5.7.1
    [2607:f130:0:d7::1e2] Our system has detected that this message does
    550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and
    550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information 550
    5.7.1 . 11si7555041plk.101 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; server.muhammadumerfarooq.me
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 69E01A0F92
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; www-data@muhammadumerfarooq.me
Arrival-Date: Fri, 29 May 2020 14:07:35 +0000 (UTC)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; mumerfarooqlablnet01@gmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;mumerfarooqlablnet01@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [2607:f130:0:d7::1e2] Our system has detected
    that this message does 550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding
    PTR records and 550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information 550
    5.7.1 . 11si7555041plk.101 - gsmtp
Subject [Being Learning] Password Reset
From    WordPress
To  mumerfarooqlablnet01@gmail.com
Date    Today 19:07
Someone has requested a password reset for the following account:

Site Name: Being Learning

Username: lablnet

If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.

To reset your password, visit the following address:

https://beinglearning.tech/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=PrkZ2f4JudxRz5PH5ikw&login=lablnet
```

Even i added IPv6 to DNS AAAA records.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what understood from the returned email, it seems the postfix is sending out the emails through IPV6 connectivity.
you may turnoff IPV6 on postfix, so the MTA would send out the emails through IPV4 which you have already defined the required records for it.

to edit this option go to:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
```

find and change inet_protocols from =all to =ipv4

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

restart your Postfix server

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me.